# replacing chars in std::stringstream inline

Tags: c++, replace, stringstream

I'm wondering if I can use std::replace to replace the double quotes in a stringstream with single quotes.

I have:

```
std::replace(
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(ssScript),
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(),
    '"', '\''
);
```

But of course ostreambuf_iterator has no default constructor, so this won't compile.

Is there another way to replace occurrences of a char in a stringstream inline like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::stringstream` class provides an interface for manipulating the stream, not its content. To manipulate the content of the stream you'd have to get the string, manipulate it and then put the string in the stream like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "\"this is a string in a stream\"";
    std::cout << "Before: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
    std::string s = ss.str();
    std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), '"', '\'');
    ss.str(s);
    std::cout << "After: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And you get:

> Before: "this is a string in a stream"
>   After: 'this is a string in a stream'

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the string copy, it's kind of inefficient, but I get your point.  I was hoping for an inline solution, but if its not possible, so be it.

Comment: @stackuser in many ways, std::stringstream is crying out for a replacement with better functionality. Perhaps boost has something you could use?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the producer of the strings is only using the `ostream` interface of the `stringstream` when producing the string, it's possible (and once you decipher the documentation, actually quite easy) to build a custom ostream that does both the filtering and appending to a string to which you have complete access.

Example:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

// a custom filter
struct replace_chars
{
    typedef char                   char_type;
    typedef io::output_filter_tag  category;


    replace_chars(char_type from, char_type to) : from(from), to(to) {}

    template<typename Sink>
    bool put(Sink& snk, char_type c)
    {
        if (c == from) c = to;
        return io::put(snk, c);
    }

    char_type from, to;
};

// some code that writes to an ostream    
void produce_strings(std::ostream& os)
{
    os << "The quick brown fox called \"Kevin\" jumps over the lazy dog called \"Bob\"" << std::endl;
    os << "leave 'these' as they are" << std::endl;
    os << "\"this\" will need to be flushed as there is no endl";
}

// test
int main()
{
    // a free buffer to which I have access
    std::string buffer;

    // build my custom ostream    
    io::filtering_ostream stream;
    stream.push(replace_chars('"', '\''));   // stage 1 - filter
    stream.push(io::back_inserter(buffer));  // terminal stage - append to string

    // pass the ostream interface of my filtering, string-producing stream    
    produce_strings(stream);
    // flush in case the callee didn't terminal with std::endl
    stream.flush();

    std::cout <<buffer <<std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
The quick brown fox called 'Kevin' jumps over the lazy dog called 'Bob'
leave 'these' as they are
'this' will need to be flushed as there is no endl
```